# How to set java modules dependency in multiple layers?

Tags: java, java-module, netbeans-11

Currently I'm checking the range of possibilities of Java module ServiceLoader for my following project.

I have (example 1):
Application folder (for purpose called FirstApplicationStructure):
    - MyApp.jar
    - lib folder for external jars
    - ext folder for my modules
MyApp application works fine.

Now, I would like to add one more layer in example 1 architecture, in the following order (example 2):
    - MainApp.jar
    - rsc folder with FirstApplicationStructure

How to set dependencies for example 2 that will make it works?
Just to make it a clearer MainApp module is MyApp, MyApp modules are in ext/lib folders.

Comment: Have you considered using Maven by any chance?

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V I'm not familiar with Maven, so how much it would take to adapt to Maven?

Comment: Maven is quite a straightforward technology, if you've used NPM, Composer, or any other form of package manager before now, it shouldn't be anything new, but if you'd like to learn, take a look at [this](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html) to start with, then I'd say just keep learning, i.e. [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-entapp.html), then try it out yourself, I promise, with the use of an IDE, it's very straightforward.

Comment: P.S. I'd start off with a JAR architecture to start with, I can't imagine you're trying to make a web application quite yet, considering you're not familiar with Maven.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V I will check those links.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V Currently I'm going through some tutorial on maven, but it came to me one thing. Does any change of libraries demands main application update? What I'm trying to do, is just to send new module, and main application would read it dynamically without any changes(update).